# Did the Moabites give water and food to B'nai Yisra'el or not? Contradictory verses?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, ki-teitzei, parshat-devarim, contradiction

[Devarim 23:4 - 5](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.23.4?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) says that we should not accept a Moabite into the nation of Israel because they did not give B'nai Yisra'el food and water as they left Egypt.

But, there is a seemingly contradictory verse in [Devarim 2:29](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.2.29?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that implies that the Moabites **did** provide B'nai Yisra'el with food and water.

How do we resolve the apparent contradiction?

Comment: Related: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4212/how-is-deut-229-reconciled-with-num-2018-21

Answer (score 2):

Ibn Ezra on Devarim 2:29 offers two possible explanations:

> as the children of Es̀av did for me Some commentators relate this
>   phrase to “you will sell me food for money” [: 28], but if this be so,
>   how can they reconcile it with the inhabitants of Ar, who are
>   Moabites, and of whom Scripture says “because they did not approach
>   you …” [23: 5]? They feel constrained to give this interpretation,
>   though, because the king of Edom said, “you shall not pass through me”
>   [Numbers 20: 18]. In my opinion, the phrase refers back to the request
>   that we go along the main highway, as the children of Es̀av did for me
>   — i.e., they let them go around Mount S̀eir along the main highway.
>   Scripture accordingly related, “You are to pass along the border of
>   your kinsmen, the Children of Es̀av, who dwell in S̀eir” [: 4].
>   However, the king of Edom did not let them pass through by way of his
>   territory (from which point they would have been close to the land of
>   Canaan), so they went on to Ar — as it is written [: 18]. Many others
>   have proposed that, although “they did not approach you” [23: 5],
>   nevertheless Israel did **purchase** from the Moabites. (Shachter/Sefaria Translation)